# How can I extract all the services from /etc/services?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to extract the services from the file `/etc/services`. The problem is that when extracting them, I get the following output when entering `head file.txt`:

```
acr-nema 
afbackup
afbackup 
afmbackup 
afmbackup
afpovertcp
afpovertcp
afs3-bos 7007
```

But the desired output should be as follows:

```
acr-nema     104/udp     dicom
afbackup     2988/tcp    #
afbackup     2988/udp
afmbackup    2989/tcp    #
afmbackup    2989/udp
afpovertcp   548/tcp     #
afpovertcp   548/udp
afs3-bos     7007/tcp    #
```

The command that I am entering is the following:

```
cat /etc/services | sed '/^#/ d' | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort | awk '!a[$0]++' > file.txt
```

Comment: Use this: `cat /etc/services | sed -e '/^#/d' -e '/^$/d' -e 's/#.*$//' | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort` to remove blank lines and the comments parts.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
 awk '$0&&/^[^#]/&&!a[$0]++' /etc/services |sort
```

btw, don't do `cat aFile|awk '...'` instead, do `awk '...' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -f1 /etc/services | grep '^[^#].*s$' | sort --unique
```

can be used to get unique services but if you want to store in a different file you can add > file.txt